# retrieve object from binding property wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Hello im trying to retrieve an object from a list of binding objects. Im using MVVM style
so i have a class name Channel. Channel has the following properties: string Name, string Label, int Id, int assignedLocation, etc..

I also have a XAML file named ChannelSetup.xaml in which there is a

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Channel #">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox "Loaded="LineComboBox_OnLoaded"....
         </GridViewColumn>
```

in my ChannelSetup.xaml.cs file i have something like this

```
this.AvailableChannelLines = new ObservableCollection<Channel>();
this.DataContext = this;
this.ListView.ItemsSource = this.AvailableChannelLines;
```

it does populate my list view correctly and everything is fine..

```
private void LineComboBox_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//// HERE I NEED TO GET THE CURRENT CHANNEL OBJECT
}
```

but when the LineComboBox_OnLoaded event gets called i want to be able to know/get the current channel object that's is being binded to. How can this be done or i need to use a different approach, methods or events??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`DataContext`** of comboBox will point to the current channel.

```
private void LineComboBox_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Channel currentChannel = (sender as ComboBox).DataContext as Channel;
}
```

Comment: thanks that was fast, i could swear i have tried that but it didnt work for me but now it does thanks a lot.